# OpenCV C++ convert buffer image from YUV 4:2:2 (UYVY format) into YUV

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, yuv

I have a video streamed from a source camera, that provides each frame into a uchar* buffer.
This buffer is YUV 4:2:2, using UYVY format.

I want to obtain a workable Mat in YUV, where I can split channels and do every filter I want.
The problem is that UYVY format is compressed and I don't find any way to explode data directly into YUV format, whitout passing from BGR.

For example, I tried this, but I don't want for performance reasons, to pass from BGR:

```
cvtColor(inMat, middleMat, COLOR_YUV2BGR_UYVY);
cvtColor(middleMat, outMat, COLOR_BGR2YUV);
```

I need something similar to:

```
cvtColor(inMat, outMat, COLOR_YUV2YUV_UYVY);
```

Thanks in advance

Giuseppe

Comment: Do you need all 3 channels, or just one?

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/c-convert-buffer-data-from-yuv-42-uyvy-format-into-yuv/10531

Comment: I need 3 channels

Comment: Conversion from UYVY to planar YUV format is possible using [sws_scale](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__libsws.html). (Part of FFmpeg). We may convert from `AV_PIX_FMT_UYVY422` to `AV_PIX_FMT_YUV444P`.